# SearchBar Numeric Keyboard Custom Renderer - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, keyboard, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to write a custom renderer that will allow me to change the keyboard type for a 'SearchBar' to be Numeric.

Here is my renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSearchBar), typeof(SearchBarRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
class CustomSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var customSearchBar = (CustomSearchBar)Element;
        customSearchBar.keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
    }
}
}
```

And then a custom control:

```
public class CustomSearchBar : SearchBar
{
    public Keyboard keyboard { get; set; }
}
```

And the usage of the custom control:

```
  var _mySearchBar = new CustomSearchBar();
```

I am a bit off here though. The `OnElementChanged` event is never hit, but even if it was it would only be setting the custom keyboard property to Numeric, not the actual KeyboardType to set the displaying keyboard. Not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

firstly I think the registering of your custom renderer is done incorrectly. probably why the OnElementChanged method is not running

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSearchBar), typeof(SearchBarRenderer))]
```

should be

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSearchBar), typeof(CustomSearchBarRenderer))]
```

Next to change the keyboard type.
In your bit of code you are setting the keyboard for the `Element` which is the Xamarin Forms element. What you want to be changing is the `Control` which is the native control.

So give this a try:
for android:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    this.Control.SetInputType(/*your keyboard type choice*/);
}
```

for ios:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    this.Control.KeyboardType = /*your keyboard type choice*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about why the renderer is not being called,it seems you registered it right, but about the part to change the keyboard, you're modifying Element, Element is the class with values which come from the Forms part, what you want to manipuate is Control what is the native control.

Also, if you want your changes to be reflected if you change the Keyboard property, you must implement a bindable property and override the `OnElementPropertyChanged` function.